# flask ajax/jquery form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

So I have this code below.
This is my jquery/ajax script

```
 $(function() {
        $(".reply").click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var element = ".comment_replies#" + id;
            $(element).show();

            $(".submit_reply#" + id).click( function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var reply_box = ".reply_box#" + id
                var data =  $(reply_box).val
                $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "{{url_for('main.HomePage')}}",
                        data: JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'),
                        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                        success: function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                            console.log(data)}
                        })


            })

    })
            })
```

here is the form:

```
<form class = "reply_form" action="#" method="post">
    <input class = "reply_box" type="text" placeholder ="write a reply" name="reply" id = "{{'id_' +com.id|string}}">
    <input type="submit" class = "submit_reply" value = "reply" id = "{{'id_' +com.id|string}}">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{com.id}}" name = "form_id">

</form>
```

and if I do:

`if request.json["data"]` in my HomePage view it somehow doesn't pass
because usually i'd just go `if request.form` when submitting the form the usual way. here is my homepage view

```
if request.json["data"] and request.method == "POST":
        return request.json["data"]
```

it's only a test to see if it return what I want it too and it fails.

am I suppose to have extra imports for `json`? because I don't have any.

I also see this error on firebug:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/homepage

400 BAD REQUEST
        11ms
```

I could submit the form the usual way but I wanna try submitting the form and appending the info without a page refresh.

Comment: `var data =  $(reply_box).val` -> `.val` should be `.val()` as it is a function.
Not sure if that is the whole problem here though.

Comment: You're also missing quite a lot of semicolons. Sure they're not mandatory, but it's always safer to use them.